# How do I check for Bluemix outages?

Tags: service, ibm-cloud, status, downtime

Is there a way of checking for [IBM Bluemix](http://www.bluemix.net) outages, and on expected resolution time for specific services?

Currently the only way I know is to submit a request and check for error code 503.  I do not know where to look for information of what services are affected and of expected resolution time for the problems.

Answer (score 1):

The [Bluemix Support Status page](https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/support/#status) provides this information. You can filter it for the region or Services that interest you, and subscribe to RSS feeds from it.